# JBoss AS 7.1.1 New missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm deploying an EAR to JBoss AS 7.1.1 that is structured like this:

```
GrahamsProj.EAR
    GrahamsProjClient.WAR
        app/GrahamsProjClient.jar
    GrahamsProjServer.EAR
        GrahamsProjServer.jar
```

Every time I deploy the EAR and startup JBoss I get this error:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:service jboss.deployment.unit."GrahamsProjServer.ear".PARSE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."GrahamsProjServer.ear"."GrahamsProjServer.jar".PARSE]

17:19:10,129 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GrahamsProjServer.ear\".\"GrahamsProjServer.jar\".PARSEjboss.deployment.unit.\"GrahamsProjServer.ear\".PARSEMissing[jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GrahamsProjServer.ear\".\"GrahamsProjServer.jar\".PARSEjboss.deployment.unit.\"GrahamsProjServer.ear\".PARSE]"]}}}
```

As you can see the error is saying that there are dependencies that my server (GrahamsProjServer.ear) can't find.

I've looked up the error by googling "new missing/unsatisfied dependencies jboss as 7" and I get a wide range of answers. The two common ones seem to be a datasource problem in standalone.xml and a problem with jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

Here is my datasource from standalone.xml:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/WorkCenterDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@MCOSRVORCL001:1521:support</connection-url>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
        <pool>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>grahamsproj</user-name>
            <password>airit</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc14">
            <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Here is the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` that's located in my WAR file's WEB-INF folder.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="GrahamsProjServer.GrahamsProjServer.jar"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

If I get rid of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` the same error shows up. So it doesn't seem to be making a difference. My problem may not be related to either one of these things. Anyone see what's going on?

Here is my `application.xml` on the server:

```
<application>
    <display-name>GrahamsProj</display-name>
    <description>GrahamsProj</description>
        <application-name>GrahamsProjServer</application-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>GrahamsProjServer.jar</ejb>
    </module>
</application>
```

Comment: Shouldnt the EAR includes the `war` as a single deployment?

Comment: Yes, the top level ear includes the client war and the server ear.

Comment: The ear inside an ear shouldn't make a difference. They are all seen as zip files, and all I have to do is go down one more level to get to it. I did that because this is just a test project, the actual project that I'm trying to transfer to JBoss 7 has several jars inside an EAR for the server.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Per J2EE spec the EAR is root level and should not contains any nested EAR.

Comment: I got it working fine with a nested EAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dependency looks bogus. Fix it to

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

you are adding dependency to submodule of your own dependency that. Probably you want to achieve that modules see each-other which the  ear-subdeployments-isolated flags enables you.

That should result in some different error. Post that one here, so we can find out what else might be wrong.

For more about class loading in AS7 and all the options that jboss-deployment-structure.xml provides please see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Given application.xml you provided, you are missing web module. There is just jar module. 
But exception should be something different.
Can you also post output of

```
jar tf <name-of-ear>
```

it will give us look into your app structure.
does exception changes in any way if you try with latest nightly build? 
https://community.jboss.org/thread/167590

Comment: do you maybe have any class-path entries in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in your GrahamsProjServer.jar?
Also how does your application.xml looks like?

Comment: The manifest in `GrahamsProjServer.jar` does not have a classpath being added in. That should be handled by JBoss right? When the jar builds a classpath is used, it's just not included in the manifest. I have the libraries as modules and a lib folder in standalone with everything needed. Also, I posted my 'application.xml' above.

Comment: can you post output of `jar tf <name-of-ear>`